# How To Make Prey Not take 'AutoFocus' Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, prey

I want to be able to run Prey - or any fullscreen program - as a solo program, but also sometimes listen to music on Chrome or Spotify. When the game is in fullscreen, I cannot access my toolbar, desktop, etc. It seems currently the only way I can get to my desktop to open another application is to

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>

to bring up the Security Options, then open Task Manager and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> out. Am I missing an easier way to do this, or do I really need to go through this process every time?

Comment: ...run it in Windowed mode?

Comment: @Frank The whole point is that I don't want to run it in Windowed mode, especially since my PC is handbuilt, and the graphics drivers HATE Windows 10 windowed

Comment: How is that a gaming issue?  Full screen gets rid of the toolbar; it's *supposed* to do that.  You get around that by windowing it.  Expected behaviour is a Windows issue, not a gaming one.

Comment: Some other games won't 'grab' Windows' attention. ex: closing chrome, leaving Prey open and minimized will shoot me right back into the Prey windows, where with for example Minecraft, it will not, and will just leave me on the desktop with a minimized game in the background

Comment: most (all?) games I've played recently on PC will yield to the windows key and open the start menu - you should also be able to simply ALT+TAB to Chrome (or other app window that is open) - simply leave Chrome always open

Comment: @HorusKol Completely forgot about Windows key *Facepalm,* anyways, yeah I could leave Chrome open but that takes processing power and memory

Comment: @David I seriously doubt that having Chrome open with an empty tab is going to have any impact your game performance/experience unless you're really at the borderline of system requirements - in which case, listening to music through Google is going to spoil it even more.

Comment: If Chrome takes too many resources, what about the File Explorer?

Comment: Don't remember if Prey has borderless, but you should use that if it does. it makes Alt tabbing a smoother process. You will need two screens if you don't want to alt+tab

Comment: Since you're using Windows 10, have you tried switching desktops? (windows Key+Tab)

Comment: @Nolonar Yes, Prey has a 'borderless windowed' option